# Subtract Hours worked from a Specified Total

Tags: excel, time, calculation

I have poked around and can't find a simple answer to this question.

I am trying to subtract the number of hours worked from a specified number of hours in Excel. The project is assigned 120 hours total. I track the number of hours worked per day, as a total not using start/stop times and have a running tally. I want to see at a glance hour many hours are still available to the project; e.g.

120h (total) - (number of hours worked to date)

All entries are in the (h):m:s format in Excel and the adding up is working correctly. But I cannot figure out how to subtract the tally from a specified total.

If I use the formula:

```
=TIME(HOUR(P1)-P2;MINUTE(P1);SECOND(P1))
```

where P1 is the total and P2 is the sum of hours worked to date, I get a #NUM error.

Comment: You set a cell format to display your time, including the number of hours greater than 24, using [this information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-subtract-time-16aa6697-6d6e-49c1-8e2c-3398a7cad6ad). Another explanation is [here](https://www.excel-exercise.com/how-to-display-hours-over-24/)

Comment: just do `P3 = P1-P2`, Then `TIME(Hour(P3),MINUTE(P3),SECOND(P3))` should be the answer.